# Django redirect not working when specifying HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: django, redirect, protocols

I am not sure why this is happening, but when I specify HTTP or HTTPS as my full URL in a redirect, the part after my domain name is appended to my current domain.

**For example:** if I redirect to https://www.external_site.com/error/page/hi_there.html it will go to https://www.currentdomain.com/error/hi_there/html

`return redirect('https://www.external_site.com/error/page/hi_there.html')`

But, when I remove the https: part (but leave the //), the redirect works as expected:

`return redirect('//www.external_site.com/error/page/hi_there.html')`

I am using Django v 1.11.23 but also tested it on Django 2.

Django runs on Apache on mod_wsgi, and goes through an IIS reverse proxy (the reverse proxy is just a reverse proxy in this instance, no special rules or anything besides to rewrite the external domain to the internal domain.)

Comment: What is displayed when you print `redirect('https://www.external_site.com/error/page/hi_there.html')`

Comment: Thanks Benbb96, I get the following when I print it out. <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="https://www.external_site.com/error/page/hi_there.html">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

It is related to "IIS reverse rewrite host in response headers" ARR setting. I disabled it by going to "IIS Manager -> Machine or Site (I used Machine so it applies to all sites) -> Application Request Routing Cache -> Server Proxy Settings and uncheck the "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" checkbox“

Now it is working as it should.